# trying to download a file from an azure file share via react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

i am trying to download a file from an azure file share via react app
i connect fine make a file client and download it using [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/sharefileclient?view=azure-node-latest#download-undefined---number--undefined---number--filedownloadoptions-)

there isn't much in the way of documentation, so i'm trying to navigate the promise to get the file contents to download them [using this](https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download)

the objects im getting returned are below from the console logging.

```
{
  "lastModified": "2020-04-09T21:01:45.000Z",
  "metadata": {},
  "contentType": "application/x-zip-compressed",
  "requestId": "xxx-401a-004e-193c-xxx",
  "version": "2019-07-07",
  "isServerEncrypted": true,
  "fileAttributes": "Archive",
  "fileCreatedOn": "2020-04-09T21:01:45.148Z",
  "fileLastWriteOn": "2020-04-09T21:01:45.148Z",
  "fileChangeOn": "2020-04-09T21:01:45.148Z",
  "filePermissionKey": "xxx*xxx",
  "fileId": "xxxxx",
  "fileParentId": "xxxxx",
  "leaseState": "available",
  "leaseStatus": "unlocked",
  "blobBody": {}
}
```

...

```
blobBody: Promise { "fulfilled" }
​​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​​
<value>: Blob
​​​
size: 1960118
​​​
type: "application/x-zip-compressed"
​​​
<prototype>: BlobPrototype
​​​​
arrayBuffer: function arrayBuffer()
​​​​
constructor: function ()
​​​​
size: 
​​​​
slice: function slice()
​​​​
stream: function stream()
​​​​
text: function text()
```

​​​​
i tried calling the stream or arrayBuffer functions, but i can't seem to access anything inside of the promise

```
console.log(`downloading file: ${fileName}`)
const fileClient = this.state.doneDirClient.getFileClient(fileName)
const file = await fileClient.download()
console.log(file)
console.log(file.blobBody.Blob)
```

last line returns `undefined`

**edit with altered code that worked:**

```
  async download(fileName: string) {
    const fileClient = this.state.doneDirClient.getFileClient(fileName)
    const file = await fileClient.download()
    Promise.resolve(file.blobBody).then(function (value) {
      fileDownload(value, fileName)
    });
  }
```

How can i get the file contents?

Comment: As per the document `file.blobBody` is a Promise. Have you tried to resolve that promise?

Comment: @GauravMantri that worked, thank you. If you'd like to post solution happy to check back and give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [`FileDownloadResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-share/filedownloadresponse?view=azure-node-latest), you will notice that `blobBody` parameter is essentially a `Promise`.

```
type FileDownloadResponse = FileDownloadHeaders & { _response: Object, blobBody: Promise<Blob>, readableStreamBody: NodeJS.ReadableStream }
```

Once you resolve that promise, you should get `Blob`.